# reuse wp query with different meta query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am querying a custom post type. I would like to output posts which fall *after* a custom date field which I can do fine. But then I want to reuse the same basic query to output posts which fall *before* the custom date field.

So I have

```
  $today = date('Ymd');
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => array( 'mypoststype' ),
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key'       => 'mypoststype_date',
            'compare'   => '<=',
            'value'     => $today,
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',       
        );
  $myposts= new WP_Query( $args );
```

then I output the necessary contents in a loop. All fine.

Next I want to have posts from the same type ordered by the same key but with compare set to '>='.

Is there some way to do this without calling a whole new query?

Comment: You could return *all* the posts in one go sorted by date. Then split them into two arrays with all posts up before the date in one array and all the ones after in another. Then you would have to sort both arrays by `meta_value_num` before finally being able to display them. So really you're better off just doing a new query :-)

Comment: You can set your 'compare' values into an array and do a foreach loop.

Comment: thanks. after fluffy kittens answer I decided to just go with another loop